# How to improve Typeahead performance by cancelling intermediate requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, typeahead.js, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm using the gems *sunspot_solr*, *sunspot_rails* and *twitter-typeahead-rails* as outlined in [this tutorial](http://blog.sed.hu/2014/06/06/ruby-on-rails-search-autocomplete-with-sunspot-solr-and-twitter-typeahead-js-part-1/). Everything is integrated and it's working well.

However, I notice that if the user pauses while typing, multiple sequential requests are made, using the values typed up to that point.

Eg, when searching for *Elizabeth Street Sydney* there are multiple GET requests:

[image]

The request is fired by Typeahead and uses the Bloodhound suggestion engine with the `remote` option pointing to a Search controller, which returns the search results in JSON format:

```
var addresses = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: '/search/query.json?q=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
  });

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null,{
  name: 'addresses',
  source: addresses
  }
}
```

Because these requests execute in order, the suggested text is not displayed until the last request finishes.

Is it possible to cancel a previous request when a new request is made? (Alternatively, is there a better way to avoid running multiple queries?)